# Что срабатывает раньше фильтр или сервлет?

Tags: java, servlet

Есть система авторизации фильтр и сервлет. Фильтр проверяет сессию на наличие id, а сервлет ходит в базу и проверяет есть ли такой пользователь. Но происходит странная вещь: авторизация не проходит с первого раза а только при наличии сессии, а инструкции `request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp")` в сервлете хоть просто игнорируются.

Вот фильтр:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    final HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    final HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
    if (nonNull(session) && sessionContainKey(session)) {

        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp")
                .forward(req, res);
    } else {

        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp")
                .forward(req, res);
    }


    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

А это сервлет:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {

        if (userExistInDB(request, getDBExecutor())) {

            setSessionAttribute(request.getSession(), request.getParameter("name"));

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp") //Вот здесь должен произойти перезод но его не происходит. Почему?
                    .forward(request, response);

        } else {...}
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

То есть проблема в том что авторизация проходит только когда сессия добавилась а с первого раза не как, хотя фильтр как мне кажется должен был уже отработать, и решение за сервлетом...

Подскажите что не так? Как мне это поправить? Спасибо.

Comment: Фильтр может срабатывать дважды. На входе и на выходе, до сервлета и после него.

Comment: Есть мнение, что в фильтре после forward не надо передавать запрос далее в цепочку.

Comment: @Sergey к сожалению когда я убираю doFilter перехода вообще не происходит(((

Comment: Можно попробовать в сервлете - `response.sendRedirect("")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первым срабатывает фильтр. Фильтр является не самым типичным примером middleware (некоторые аспекты могут поначалу вызвать недоумение, например, обычно управлением filter chain занимается внешний код на основе ответа метода фильтрации), через который проходит запрос перед тем, как приземлиться в сервлете. Логика фильтра предполагает, что если он завершил обработку до сервлета, и сервлету запрос передавать не надо (например, если запрос пришел не с тем content-type, его проще обрубить на входе), то он просто не будет вызывать `chain.doFilter()`, и объект ответа уже будет проинициализирован с необходимыми значениями. В данном примере `.doFilter()` вызывается всегда, что означает, что запрос точно дойдет до сервлета и будет обработан - и, видимо, повторный вызов `request.getRequestDispatcher()` просто переписывает старое значение новым. Чтобы от этого избавиться, необходимо просто не вызывать `filterChain.doFilter()`.